# I want to display data from phpmyadmin(chat data) only display for session user

Tags: php, session, phpmyadmin

I want to make it display only chat name that only for certain session user. Something like `if else statement id=name`.

There are tables for this problem, user table and chat table.

The id is from user table, while name is the from chat table. I need it to classify to display chat data only for id that sign in from session based on id=name.

Can someone help me write the code?

I need an if else statement for id=name in php to display chat data

```
<span style="color: green;"> <?= $row['name'];?> :</span>
<span style="color: brown;"><?= $row['message'];?> </span>
<span style="float:right;"><?= $row['date'];?></span>
```

Comment: First of all you should share that you have tried. and second you need to build relation between user table and chart table. then you can easily get specific data from both table by using the joins. 
Remember: Please share what you have tried

Comment: i got everything works the message chat script, but its just display all the message from other user too. i need it to display only to the user that sign in on their session only.

Comment: i got problem to post all the code here, its say wrong format. im new to stack overflow